# Restricting users to specific VPS IP addresses

Tags: windows-server-2008, ip, vps

The case is that I have a VPS with 10 different IP address, there are 10 users that can login on the server. The users are logging in via the windows account control, so not via active directory.

I want to distribute the IP addresses between my user account, so that every user hase a unique ip address when the make a request outside the internal network.

For example. User A goes to myip.com and gets 188.12.12.12 and User B gets 188.12.12.13.

Is this possible? If not is there another way?

Comment: Um...  Why?  It's not going to help with bandwidth, you know.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by logging in?  Is this a remote desktop server, a VPN, or what?

Comment: Its a virtual server that runs on virtual box. The users logging in on windows 2008 server with there user credentials.

Comment: But **how** are they logging it?  What exactly are you trying to accomplish by giving out unique addresses?

Comment: Why would every user need a unique ip address? They each have a uniquer user account. I don't see what this would accomplish.

Comment: I don't think there is either a clean solution or any possible use case for this.

Comment: Are they all connecting to the same VPS or different VPSes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having the 10 different IPs on the server isn't the problem. On the client machines you need to set them so that they request the proper IP you want them to connect to. This can be done through a DNS hosts file (on the client machine) or through a DNS server. You would need to assign a name to each machine (eg. john.local.domain - John's Workstation VPS).

On the server there really isn't going to be a way to determine if some user is connecting then give some IP without making a connection (via TCP/IP) first.

If you're talking about outside the internal network then you can use NAT or VPN to setup controls on what each account can access in the Router itself.

**Update**

In the VPS you can specify a specific ip address on the local network that you allow a user to connect from if you're doing this for security.